# How to get height of Page?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I get the height of a Page?, i.e; the height of all elements in the page.

For example, if I have this XAML which makes a Page, how can I get the height at runtime?

```
<Page x:Class="DialogViews.SomeError"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400"
    Title="SomeMessage">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DialogTitleError}">A Problem</Label>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=DialogMsg}">
            Some message to user
        </TextBlock>
        <Label Grid.Row="2" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Hyperlink>
                Some link for info
            </Hyperlink>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**Reason:**

I've created a custom Window that will display as a Dialog message to the user, the Window contains a Frame which in-turn contains this Page. I'm trying to fix the height of the Window to that of the Page.

**I have tried:**

```
myPage.Height; //NaN
myPage.ActualHeight; //0
```

Comment: Where are you getting the Actual Height? After it appears, or after you do a new() call? ActualHeight after doing a new() will always be zero.

Comment: @Bob. Yes, you're right, I'm calling just just after new(). But I don't think it matters because by the time it's loaded it will already have been stretched and ActualHeight will not be what I'm after.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a Frame to hold other content as well? If its just the `Page` I'd suggest just putting the `Page` into the Window.

Comment: @Bob. Yes, I have the Page in a Frame. The Window has the Frame and other content.

Comment: Hmm... my answer would work as your solution if the `Page` is the same width as your `Frame` since `SizeToContent` property sizes to the `Content` inside the `Window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fit the size of the Window to your user control `Page`, then I would suggest trying the [SizeToContent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.sizetocontent.aspx) property of Window.

```
 <Window x:Class "MyNameSpace.MyWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         SizeToContent="Height" />
```

Height - Specifies that a window will automatically set its height to fit the height of its content, but not the width.

Edit: This will stretch your Window to fit the Frame, which hopefully is set to change with the widths/heights of your Page.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for

```
  SystemParameters.FixedFrameVerticalBorderWidth
  SystemParameters.FixedFrameHorizontalBorderHeight
  SystemParameters.WindowCaptionHeight
```

Please check this [msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/87b7c373-2d44-4653-ac9f-4ba17a2c5b58)

Comment: Hi, no sorry that's not it. The height of all elements on the Page are variable, I need the height of the Page not the window.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
this.Height;<br/>
this.Width;
```

Comment: Mark as answered so this will helpfull for others

Comment: @Ashaar: I have already said that this answer did not help, I already tried (as stated in my question).